# print not workig on IE11

Tags: javascript, angular, file, blob

i am using blob url and iFrame to print document. It's work fine in Chrome but not working in IE.

can anyone tell me how to print blob url set in iframe src?

```
let file = new Blob([res.blob()], { type: 'application/pdf' });

let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);// here file is blob object
let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');                        

document.getElementById('viewerContainer').appendChild(iframe);

iframe.onload = function () {
    iframe.contentWindow.print();
};

iframe.src = blobURL;
```

Comment: Please be more precise than _"but not working"_. Any errors (in the console)?

Comment: Any errors? Did you check the web dev tools (F12)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print Iframe with PDF generated on the fly IE 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26147064/print-iframe-with-pdf-generated-on-the-fly-ie-11)

Comment: i am using 12 page document. when i try to print all page then this code work on only first page.

Comment: no error found in console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IE11 Windows 7 Print issue after kb4021558](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547861/ie11-windows-7-print-issue-after-kb4021558)

Comment: i try it also but its not working to print blob file data

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specific case of IE7 but I had a similar error with Firefox. This one triggers the onload event before the content is fully loaded. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution. So I cunningly used a setTimeout(). 
This solution is weak but you can use setTimeout(time) with a time that will allow you to load the full content of the document. **Warning** this time depends on the network connection

Comment: You need to revise your answer. Don't put important information in a comment.

Comment: it's not work for me. when i use iframe.contentWindow.print() for IE11 its print only first page of document with all visible website contents

Comment: It's the same if you use `setTimeout(iframe.contentWindow.print(), 5000)` ?

Comment: let iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
                        iframe.onload = function () {
                            setTimeout(iframe.contentWindow.print(), 5000)
                        };
                        iframe.src = blobURL;